# Using ExtJS how do I specify '->' minus a little bit?

Tags: extjs

I have a component that I want to align to the right but would like to bring it back just a little bit...

```
me.dockedItems = [ {
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock: 'top',
    items:
    [{
        text: i18n.user_new,
        disabled: false,
        action: 'add',
        iconCls: 'icon-user-add'
    }, 

    '->',  // is there a way to say align right minus 20px?

    {
        fieldLabel: i18n.filter,
        labelWidth: 40,
        xtype: 'filterfield'
    }],
    ...
```

What do I change the '->' to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way (IMO) is to specify a margin:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var form = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        renderTo: document.body,
        dockedItems : [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            items: [{
                text: 'B1'
            }, '->', {
                text: 'B2',
                margin: '0 20 0 0'
            }]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a specific config for that but you could add spacers after your toolbar item to push it away from the right side, e.g.: `'->','yourOwnConfig',' ',' '`

In other words, `' '` is equivalent to a small space on the toolbar, you can add more of them side-by-side for however much space you need on the right side.

Or using your example:

```
me.dockedItems = [ {
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock: 'top',
    items:
    [{
        text: i18n.user_new,
        disabled: false,
        action: 'add',
        iconCls: 'icon-user-add'
    }, 

    '->',  // is there a way to say align right minus 20px?

    {
        fieldLabel: i18n.filter,
        labelWidth: 40,
        xtype: 'filterfield'
    },' ',' ',' ',' '],
```

I don't know how many of them is equivalent to 20px but I think you get the idea.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply @Geronimo .  I had already ended up doing something similar but added only one extra element to the items array...

`items: [ myButtonOnLeft, '->', myComponentOnRight, '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' ]`

there still may be a better answer but this will work for now.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can add box:

```
{
   xtype: 'box',
   width: 20
}
```

Comment: seems like adding a container is a little much given that a margin gives the same precision as in Evan's example